# How portable is code using wmemset()?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, portability, memset

Currently our code uses a for-loop for filling a buffer holding a Unicode string with some Unicode character value (of type `wchar_t`). There's [`wmemset()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1fdeehz6(VS.80).aspx) function in Visual C++ using which we could replace a loop with a single function call in that code. However we're concerned about portability - we'd like to leave code as portable as possible and so introducing non-portable or poorly portable stuff is a bad idea.

Will using `wmemset()` hurt portability and to what extent?

Comment: There's also `std::fill` which is perfectly portable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's mentioned in the C++ standard `cwchar` (Table 48) at least and hence should be pretty standard. So I guess it should not hurt portability